# Mixture of encodings

Tags: emacs, character-encoding, gedit

For a text which is a mixture of different encodings, 
is there no way to find all encodings? And convert them to a single encoding such as utf8?

I copied from different sources possibly with different encodings into a text file under gedit. Surprisinly, I seldom have to considered the mixture of encodings problem. Wonder why?

But when I open such files under emacs, it seems that I have to face the problem.

If I create a text file by copying from different sources into emacs, and then open the text file under gedit, will it be the same? I.e. will it be fine in emacs, but not in gedit?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, because the *validity ranges* of different encodings do overlap, thus one cannot unequivocally determine which chunk of text has which encoding.

You might not like the answer, but these are the facts, in my opinion.